# So if you can't make GUI's with just pure Python, how does Tkinter do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, libraries

So, I have been wanting to make my own GUI library for Python 3. And I couldn't find anything anywhere on where to start. So I decided to ask the question here.
Goal:
Be able to make Python Libraries without using other libraries.

Edit:

So, If I was to make a Library in C for Python. How would I go about doing that.

Comment: Many Python libraries are in fact written in C++ with provided Python's syntax access to its functionality

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean when you say your goal is to "make libraries without using other libraries?"

Programming and software engineering relies heavily on the work that other people have done in the course of multiple years and creating everything from scratch is not only cumbersome, but impossible.

Comment: FYI, `tkinter` is an interface to `tk`, which is written in C. Similar Python bindings exist for other UI toolkits, such as Qt. You could also use the `ctypes` module to call Windows' (or some other operating system's) UI routines directly from Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter is a python wrapper around tcl/tk's GUI toolkit , similar to how PySide/PyQt and wxPython are wrappers around the Qt and Wx C++ GUI toolkits.

If you wanted to build your own from scratch you would have to make use of existing operating system APIs and/or use something cross platform like OpenGL. For a good example of the latter you can look into Kivy, which is built on OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Different operating systems have different API's for doing GUI's. So *how* you have to do it very much depends on the operating system. I think one of the reasons that Python uses Tkinter is because it was already ported to different operating systems.

GUI API's are typically provided as *shared libraries*, often written in or compatible with C.

If you want to use those from Python, you will have to write a Python wrapper for them. For example using [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). Doing that requires a significant understanding of (1) Python, (2) `ctypes` and (3) the GUI API in question. If more than one of these technologies is new to you, I would not recommend taking on such a project.